# Cannot Install statnet Package in R Studio

Tags: r, installation, statnet

I got the following warning and error messages while I was trying to install the statnet package:

```
> installing *source* package 'statnet' ...
> 
> package 'statnet' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> 
> R
> 
> inst
> 
> byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
> 
> Warning: package 'tergm' was built under R version 3.5.3
> 
> Warning: package 'ergm' was built under R version 3.5.3
> 
> Warning: package 'network' was built under R version 3.5.3
> 
> Error: package or namespace load failed for 'network' in
> loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
> vI[[j]]):  there is no package called 'tibble'
> 
> Error : package 'network' could not be loaded
> 
> ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'statnet'
> 
> removing 'C:/Users/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/statnet
> 
> In R CMD INSTALL
> 
> Warning in install.packages :
> 
>   installation of package ‘statnet’ had non-zero exit status
```

May I know how to solve the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please always remove these `>` before posting your question.

Comment: What R version are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.5.1

Comment: Upgrade R and try again.

Comment: It gives another error now:   ERROR: dependency 'network' is not available for package 'statnet'

Comment: I think you need to install with all dependencies set to `TRUE`. Try `install.packages("statnet",dependencies=TRUE)`. It seems to be available on CRAN.

Comment: I got the same error after running this line of code

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `sessionInfo()` and all code you've since ran. Also include any new errors. Do you have Rtools installed?

Comment: Thanks, bro.  The installation works now.  What I did basically was rebooting the rstudio and then installed the package with all dependencies set to TRUE. Thanks again!

Comment: Great, glad to know.

Comment: I would add that it is a good practice to specify the version (as noted by @NelsonGon) using the function sessionInfo() from the utils package.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would restart your R session. The error message:

```
there is no package called 'tibble'
```

Indicates that you don't have the `tibble` package. Simillary, the error message

```
Error : package 'network' could not be loaded
```

Indicates that you don't have the `network` package.

I would install these packages on the console by typing:

```
install.packages(c("tibble", "network"),dependencies=TRUE))
```

Then try to install your package.

```
install.packages("statnet", ,dependencies=TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for me...